# Use of colorbar() matplotlib associated to a axes

Tags: matplotlib

I want to have a quick contourf() plot with colorbar().

If I have just one plot I use:

```
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='RdGy')
plt.colorbar();
```

But if I use axes, how I should do? I.e.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)

ax[0].contourf(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='RdBu');
ax[1].contourf(Y, X, Z, 20, cmap='RdBu');

ax[0].colorbar(); #does not work
```

I'd like to have something quicker than define a divider manually, etc.., as simple as plt.colorbar() on the first example.

Answer (score 1):

[`colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar) is a method of the figure. It takes a ScalarMappable as input and optionally an axes next to which the colorbar is placed.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)

im = ax[0].contourf(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='RdBu')
im2 = ax[1].contourf(Y, X, Z, 20, cmap='RdBu')

fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax[0])
```

There is a discussion about making colorbar available as axes method on [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12333). Feel free to contribute.

Comment: I can confirm this works perfectly. In fact if an axes contains a ScalarMappable, the colorbar could be made smart enough to understand that, and make it a method of the axes. I will check the discussion in github.